# Are there any alternatives to the default terminal, pantheon terminal?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

What are the alternatives available for pantheon-terminal for elementary OS?

Comment: List questions are discouraged on SE, and are likely to be closed except in very rare cases. We made a few exceptions on AU because they'd already existed and become useful, but I'd advise not follow that.

Comment: I always agree with you @RolandiXor :), thanks for advice, I knew its `too broad` (wrt [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139618/are-list-questions-off-topic)) but expected exception.

Comment: For me it's **lilyterm**: https://lilyterm.luna.com.tw/.
  `sudo apt install lilyterm`

Answer (score 4):

## [Gnome Terminal](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/):

The Gnome terminal supports multiple profiles, you can install from the Software Center or with this command

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [Guake](https://github.com/Guake/guake)

> Guake is a dropdown terminal made for the GNOME desktop environment.

[image: Guake]

Instalation:

you can install from the Software Center or with this command

```
sudo apt-get install guake
```

Comment: How to install? ping me with @Ravan after adding steps to install, I will come and give you upvote :)

Comment: @Ravan I've updated my answer

Comment: This is my best lite terminal for quick editing!

Answer (score 2):

## [Xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html)

> The xterm program is a terminal emulator for the X Window System.

[image]

Instalation:

you can install from the Software Center or with this command

```
sudo apt-get install xterm
```

Comment: How to install? ping me with @Ravan after adding steps to install, I will come and give you upvote :)

Comment: @Ravan I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Terminator](http://gnometerminator.blogspot.co.uk/p/introduction.html):

Terminator supports multiple terminals windows.You can change the size, colour, give different shapes to the terminal. Its very user friendly.

Install from the Software Center or with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install terminator
```

To split/open new tab, right click on the terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Konsole](https://konsole.kde.org/)

> Konsole is a terminal emulator for the K Desktop Environment.

[image]

Installation:

you can install from the Software Center or with this command

```
sudo apt-get install konsole
```