# Can I make elementary terminal look like Ubuntu 14.04 Terminal?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I want to ask how can I make elementary OS terminal to look like Ubuntu 14.04 terminal. I don't like the design of elementary OS terminal.

Comment: Install `gnome-terminal`. btw `pantheon-terminal` is the most lightweight terminal, use less CPU iirc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its not possible to convert elementary terminal to Ubuntu terminal. The possible case is: Install Ubuntu terminal i.e.,`gnome-terminal`

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

- To change default terminal,see:

  [How can I change the default Terminal app?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1344/how-can-i-change-the-default-terminal-app)
- To launch from app launcher:

  [Unable to launch gnome-terminal from app launcher](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3031/unable-to-launch-gnome-terminal-from-app-launcher)
- For alternatives to `pantheon-terminal` see

  [Are there any alternatives to the default terminal, pantheon terminal?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3028/are-there-any-alternatives-to-the-default-terminal-pantheon-terminal)